# How to disable automatic style to img in ckeditor?

Tags: ckeditor

There is one problem when I work with ckeditor. I press on icon for adding images, then modal window appears and I put direct image link in the special field, in this moment width and height detected automatically and it writes to style for ex:

```
<img src='#some images direct link' style='width:SOME WIDTH;height:SOME HEIGHT'>
```

Can I disable this automatic function? Or I have to delete this style by myself every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a rule for your config that would remove the style tag on  elements.

```
  var editorRulesObject = {
    elements: {
      img: function( el ) {
        if(el.attributes.style) {
          el.attributes.style = '';
        }
      }
    }
  };

  CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function( e ) {
    // Ensures that any non-styled text, or text input without any tags will be correctly styled.
    CKEDITOR.instances[e.editor.name].dataProcessor.dataFilter.addRules( editorRulesObject );
    CKEDITOR.instances[e.editor.name].dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( editorRulesObject );
  });
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much. It works like a charm. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In 2020, since version 4.5.0, it is much easier to switch off the annoying automatic filling in of height and readiness.
New there is the config option "image_prefillDimensions".

```
config.image_prefillDimensions = false;
```

Documentation: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-image_prefillDimensions

The user still has the possibility to fill in the height and width automatically by clicking on the button [Reset size (circle arrow)].